# Is it possible to create entry into LDAP server without RDN with only attributes?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, apacheds, ldapjs

We are using ldapjs node module to communicate with LDAP servers like Microsoft Active Directory, Apache DS and Open LDAP. As per our understanding from [here](https://ldap.com/ldap-dns-and-rdns/):

> DNs can be comprised of zero or more components, which means that it is legal to have a DN without any components at all.

Is it possible to create entry into LDAP server with only attributes without any RDN in my Base DN?

For example, if I wanted to create `inetOrgPerson` entry into LDAP server without RDN, creating entry as below:

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({  
  url: 'ldap://xxxxxxxx:389'
});
client.bind('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', function(err) {
  if(err){
      console.log('error',err);
  }else{
      console.log('bind is success');
  }
});

var newDN = "ou=testou,dc=xxxx,dc=com";
var newUser = {    
    objectClass: 'inetOrgPerson',
    sn: 'test'
  }

client.add(newDN, newUser, function(err) {  
  if(err){
      console.log('error',err);
  }else{     
      client.unbind(function(err) {
          if(err){
              console.log('error unbind : ',err);
          }else{
              console.log('unbind is success');
          }
        });
  }
})
```

After executing above code there should be entry in the `OU` `testou` with `sn` as `test`. Any inputs will help. Thank you all.

Comment: What do you mean 'without RDN'? when you are using the RDN 'ou=testou,dc=xxxx,dc=com'?

Comment: As per the RFC4514 the RDN will have any one below:
      CN  -    commonName (2.5.4.3)
      L     -  localityName (2.5.4.7)
      ST  -   stateOrProvinceName (2.5.4.8)
      O   -    organizationName (2.5.4.10)
      OU  -    organizationalUnitName (2.5.4.11)
      C    -   countryName (2.5.4.6)
      STREET - streetAddress (2.5.4.9)
      DC  -    domainComponent (0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25)
      UID  -   userId (0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1)
Now when I say without RDN, without any of the attribute type in DN. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is legal to have a DN with zero component, it is reserved for the rootDSE.
It is mandatory for any entry to have a non-empty DN, and therefore to have a non-empty RDN.